# When importing unstructured data - audio and video file - into HDFS, are those files split into block?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When importing unstructured data - audio and video file - into HDFS, are those files splited into 128MB block and saved like other data does?

Answer (score 0):

Blocks are created, yes. It is then up to the client to determine how to re-assemble the files into proper blobs, which is why object/blob storage, such as [Apache Ozone](https://ozone.apache.org/), would be recommended for these filetypes, rather than HDFS block storage.

Comment: I didn’t catch that, how is ozone block distribution logic different from HDFS? What do you mean by ‘client to determine how to re-assemble’

Comment: @AyushSaxena Ozone is not blocks. It's blobs like S3. For reassembly, not at all file types are splitable. For example, 2 lines of a CSV can be reordered for mapreduce analysis purposes. Two bytes of a document/audio/video files really cannot be reordered at all. But if you're a committer, I assume you understand that

Comment: Ozone does have blocks, It does allocate blocks: Blocks forms Containers and so on. Ozone itself is inherited from HDFS concepts. Check these files https://github.com/apache/ozone/blob/master/hadoop-ozone/ozone-manager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/ozone/om/request/key/OMAllocateBlockRequestWithFSO.java and for EC files it does have block groups as well similar to HDFS:  https://github.com/apache/ozone/blob/master/hadoop-hdds/docs/content/feature/EC-Write-Block-Allocation-in-Containers.png

Comment: Even the doc has mentions: https://ci-hadoop.apache.org/view/Hadoop%20Ozone/job/ozone-doc-master/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/hadoop-hdds/docs/public/concept/containers.html
https://ci-hadoop.apache.org/view/Hadoop%20Ozone/job/ozone-doc-master/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/hadoop-hdds/docs/public/concept/datanodes.html